# linq xml select node

Tags: xml, linq

I have xml document:

```
<users>
        <user_tuple>
          <userid>U01</userid>
          <code>
            <name>Tom Jones</name>
          </code>
          <rating>B</rating>
        </user_tuple>
        <user_tuple>
          <userid>U02</userid>
          <code>
             <name>Mary Doe</name>
          </code>
          <rating>A</rating>
        </user_tuple>
        <user_tuple>
          <userid>U03</userid>
          <code>
            <name>Dee Linquent</name>
          </code>
         <rating>D</rating>
        </user_tuple>
```

How do I select only those (and all child nodes/elements) where Element("userid").value=="U01" and Element("name").Value=="Tom Jones" etc ie I want results:

```
 <user_tuple>
      <userid>U01</userid>
      <code>
        <name>Tom Jones</name>
      </code>
      <rating>B</rating>
    </user_tuple>
```

I'm using C#

```
public void searchInfo(string rootNode, string Element1Name, string Element2Name,  string Element1Val, string Element2Val){ 

////// Select rootNode and all descend nodes

    var res = root.Elements("rootNode")
       .Where(
          x => 
             (string)x.Element(Element1Name) == Element1Val&&
             (string)x.Element(Element2Name) == Element2Val)
       ).ToList();
///////////    

foreach (var node in res){
 Debug.Writeline("Name {0} Value {1}", node.Name, node.Value)

}
```

Example:

searchInfo("rootNode","userid","code", "U01", "Tom Jones")

```
res =  <userid>U01</userid>
          <code>
            <name>Tom Jones</name>
          </code>
          <rating>B</rating>

and result:
userid U01
name Tom Jones 
rating B
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're working in C# or Visual Basic? Linq is available in both. Actually, in my opinion a few XML operations are easier in VB than C#.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
var res = doc.Elements("users").Elements("user_tuple")
   .Where(
      x => 
         (string)x.Element("userid") == "U01" &&
         (string)x.Element("code").Element("name") == "TomJones")
   ).ToList();
```

Or use XPath:

```
var res = doc.XPathSelectElements("
                users/user_tuple[userid='U01' and code[name='TomJones']]
          ").ToList();
```

Comment: Do you need to specify the descendants?

Comment: `doc.Descendants().Where...` really?!?! It will make the query perform huge amount of unnecessary work...

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek you right, it's better to use `doc.Elements("users").Elements("user_tuple")`